# ComponentLookupError when testing with plone.app.testing on Plone 3.x

Tags: testing, plone, functional-testing

I ran into this error running the test for my product, written using plone.app.testing on Plone 3.3.5:

```
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass plone.app.viewletmanager.interfaces.IViewletSettingsStorage>, '')
```

but the product works correctly outside of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I specified the wrong version for plone.testing.

These are the correct versions to use with Plone 3.x ATM (december 2011):

```
plone.app.testing = 3.0a1
plone.testing = 3.0a2
```

The error above was caused by plone.testing being pinned to 3.0a1.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. I didn't know plone.app.testing was compatible with plone 3 at all.